# Revert in new GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I was just curious, since I switched from the "old" GitHub Desktop Client to the newer one it seems that the `revert option` (pic) has disappeared.

Old client:

[image]

New client:

[image]

So I wanted to ask you guys: Is this a bug? Am I the only one experiencing this? Or is this purpose and if so, is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally wrote an email to the GitHub support and they told me that this function is still pending/ under development, so it *is* indeed only missing at the moment ([like it´s mentioned here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/752)) and will be in the final version of *GitHub Desktop*. Just in case anyone else was wondering...

I will update this answer according to the development state.

**Update:** This function was implemented with [0.8.0](https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/) of GitHub Desktop and works just fine.

**Update 2:** As this is a pretty old release it can't be found using the link above so here is [the link](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/releases/tag/release-0.8.0) to the release in Git.